# How can I enable my modifications to a library/package without modifying its source?

Tags: elisp, python

I have been using a forked version of python.el for some time in which I have changed the indentation rules so that instead of

```
something.method1()\
         .method2()
```

and

```
stuff = (1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6)
```

I get

```
something.method1()\
    .method2()
```

and

```
stuff = (1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6)
```

My changes are on GitHub at [this commit](https://github.com/asmeurer/python.el/commit/fb3e50234583406174cb725727ef7242951b9875) and [this commit](https://github.com/asmeurer/python.el/commit/5d5253f46235af8d9ec1f0519aee0e769956de58), respectively.

The problem is that my forked version of python.el is out of date, and there's been a lot of development since then.  So my question is: *how can I make the same changes by modifying my init file, without modifying the source of python.el?*

Comment: If you've only modified a function or two, why not put your versions in your init file *after* you load `python.el`?  Your modified functions will then clobber the originals.

Comment: Seems like a good use-case for the advice mechanism.  I'll try to write up a proper answer later when I have more time.

Comment: I like to clobber and completely take over major and minor modes --  :) -- I make them my own by adding prefixes to everything and making new libraries -- then, I modify the daylights out of them. If I want the default behavior, it's always there by calling the original modes.

Answer (score 3):

That's what the advice mechanism is for.  Look up `advice-add` or `defadvice`.

This said, what you describe sounds not terribly specific to your use-case, so an even better solution is to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and attach your changes as a patch.